# Getting value of dynamically generated dropdown Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, null

Today I got stuck in a peculiar issue. It looked pretty basic to me but somehow I have spent more than 2 hours on it and its still not resolved.

I have a dropdown which I am generating dynamically.
jQuery Version - v1.11.1

```js
 var pagename="Spend Impact";
 var countryChannelObj = null;
 var DEFAULT_COUNTRY = "US";
  $.ajax({
         url: 'digitalImpactHeaders',
           success: function(data) {
             $(document).ready(function(){
              countryChannelObj = data;
              populateImpactCountry(DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
              populateImpactHeader(DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
             });
           }
         });
 

/*
{
    "US": [
        "Display",
        "Paid Social"
    ],
    "DE": [
        "Non-IM Mktg Initiatives",
        "Paid Social",
        "Programmatic",
        "Display"
    ],
    "UK": [
        "Programmatic",
        "Paid Social",
        "Display",
        "Non-IM Mktg Initiatives"
    ]
}
*/


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#impactCountry").change(function(){
     var country = $("#impactCountry").val();
     populateImpactHeader(country);
    });
    
    populateMonthlyImpactDataOnLoad();
    
    
    function populateMonthlyImpactDataOnLoad(){
     var endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //CurrentDate
     var startDate  = moment(endDate).startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     populateImpactData(startDate,endDate);
    }

    function populateQuarterlyImpactData(){
     var endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //CurrentDate
     var startDate = getQuarterFirstDay(new Date());
    }

    function populateYearlyImpactData(){
     var endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //CurrentDate
     var startDate = moment(endDate).dayOfYear(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }

    function populateCustomDatesImpactData(){
     var endDate = $("#impactEndDate").val();
     var startDate = $("#impactStartDate").val();
    }

     function getQuarterFirstDay (currentDate) {
        var m = d.getMonth() - d.getMonth() % 3;
        return moment(new Date(d.getFullYear(), m, 1)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    }
    
    
     
     function populateImpactData(startDate,endDate){
     
       
       var country = $('#impactCountry option:selected').val();
       console.log("countryName is ==>"+country);
       var channel = $("#impactChannel option:selected").val();
       console.log("channel is ==>"+channel);
           
});


function populateImpactCountry(defaultCountry){
 $.each(countryChannelObj, function(index){
  $("#impactCountry").append($("<option />").val(index).text(index));
 });
 $('#impactCountry option[value="'+defaultCountry+'"]').attr("selected",true);
}

function populateImpactHeader(country){
 $("#impactChannel").html("");
 var channelData = countryChannelObj[country];
 if(channelData.length >0){
  $("#impactChannel").append($("<option />").val("All").text("All"));
 }
 $.each(channelData, function(index) {
  $("#impactChannel").append($("<option />").val(channelData[index]).text(channelData[index]));
 });
}
```

```html
    <select id="impactCountry" name="impactCountry"></select>

    <select  id="impactChannel" name="impactChannel" ></select>
```

With the code provided I am able to populate the dropdowns with dynamic values.
Now, I want to get the selected value of this dropdown after the page loads for the first time (There is no change event happening. Right after page load). Whenever I do

```
var country = $('#impactCountry option:selected').val(); //undefined
var channel = $("#impactChannel option:selected").val(); //undefined


var country = $('#impactCountry').val();  //null
var channel = $("#impactChannel").val();  //null
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. One thing that I can think of is that since the options are dynamically introduced to the page the browser is not able to register these pages and hence when I do a .val() it does not know if these nodes even exist.

I tried searching for similar post but couldnt find it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vatsal Pande

Comment: where is the surrounding code you have to get the val()? Is it in an event? if it is, show that code

Comment: you dont need the `$(document).ready(function() {` inside the success callback.

Comment: you are using `countryChannelObj` in a place it's not defined, pass the `countryChannelObj` to the populateImpactCountry function, i.e. `populateImpactCountry("US", countryChannelObj);`

Answer (score 2):

Three things.

1. You need to populate them inside `$(document).ready()` function.
2. Use [`$.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) to get the dropdown values.
3. `countryChannelObj` is `undefined`. Fix that.

Comment: Its not much actually. I just need to get the value of selected value of dynamically generated dropdown :)

Comment: $.ajaxComplete is a global event and can only be applied to whole document so I used complete method  provided by $.ajax. It is a local event and works specific to my need. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`countryChannelObj` is not defined at the point that the function (populateImpactCountry) is defined.

As you are using ajax, you'll need to pass the `countryChannelObj` to the function in order to use it inside the function body:

`populateImpactCountry("US", countryChannelObj);`

then inside the function:

`function populateImpactCountry(defaultCountry, countryChannelObj) {`

You also done need the `$(document).ready(function() {` inside the success.

Comment: Edited my post. countryChannelObj was global object only. I missed it in the post. Having document.ready inside ajax wont cause any problem. On the contrary, it may give you some performance benefit as the page wont wait to fire the call till the whole page is loaded.
You may read this for further reading     

https://alexsexton.com/blog/2010/01/dont-let-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Comment: did you read the full post and comments of that 5 year old link?

Comment: I did.. even if it is 10 years old you can always get some pointers that you may use somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @Vatsal, had assumed that you were having trouble with dynamically creating the options in your drop-down. Apparently not :) I've edited my answer.

1) Firstly, it is better to do the AJAX call within the document.ready(). Since **your AJAX call could take longer than page load**, the countryChannelObj will be empty when your document.ready() function runs. Also, it is better to use it only for data retrieval and perform population of data within document.ready() function.

2) If you still want to use the $.ajax before document.ready(), use a timer within your document.ready() to continuously check when the countryChannelObj is not null and then run your data population functions. You can clear the timer once you find the data.

I've tried to do something similar in the following jsBin:
http://jsbin.com/pagahabizo/1/edit?js,output

Hope it helps !

Comment: Edited my post. countryChannelObj was global object only. I missed it in the post